# Building Krita from Source Mac

Tags: macos, cmake, package, open-source

I've been trying to build the dependencies for Krita from source on Mac and keep running into the following bug:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `ext_pkgconfig'.  Stop.
Error: Printing last lines of log output
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./iconv.3.html /Users/callum/dev/i/share/doc//iconv.3.html
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./iconv_close.3.html /Users/callum/dev/i/share/doc//iconv_close.3.html
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./iconv_open.3.html /Users/callum/dev/i/share/doc//iconv_open.3.html
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./iconv_open_into.3.html /Users/callum/dev/i/share/doc//iconv_open_into.3.html
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./iconvctl.3.html /Users/callum/dev/i/share/doc//iconvctl.3.html
[100%] Completed 'ext_iconv'
[100%] Built target ext_iconv
Build Success! ext_iconv
Building ext_pkgconfig
make: *** No rule to make target `ext_pkgconfig'.  Stop.
Error: Failed build ext_pkgconfig
 build fail, attempting known fixes...
Error building package ext_pkgconfig, stopping...
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I've tried installing all the packages I can think that would be causing it with little luck.

Working on Mac 13.3.1 (a), cmake version 3.26.3, GNU Make 3.81.

I found that uninstalling stuff like pkgconfig and any other packages that have been giving me problems using brew has helped the installation process. This being said, it has been running for the last 12 hours...

Comment: please add version numbers for all the things. krita, CMake, Make, macOS, pkgconfig